# Is it permissible to marry a banker's son?

Tags: nikah

Is it permissible in Islam to marry a person whose parents are bank employees?

The groom is a very humble and down-to-earth person, as well as *namazi*.

Please help me out to find what Islam says about this.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about this site and the stack exchange model I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and check the [help].

Comment: I'd be glad to know what kind of influence the job of the parents of your groom would have on your marriage? First working in a bank per se is not haram. 2nd assuming their job is haram i still have no clue why you ask whether it is permissible or not to marry this person. As the problem at the end would be with the earnings of his parents and this problem can be solved easily by given the riba part as sadaqah etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is permissible. Whether working in a bank is permissible or not is debatable. Even if it's haram, you may still marry a bankers son because Allah says:

> And no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another. And if a
>   heavily laden soul calls [another] to [carry some of] its load,
>   nothing of it will be carried, even if he should be a close relative.
>   You can only warn those who fear their Lord unseen and have
>   established prayer. And whoever purifies himself only purifies himself
>   for [the benefit of] his soul. And to Allah is the [final]
>   destination. (Quran 35:18)

Comment: I was about to say that verse! :)